# Connection to sql server is not possible

Tags: mysql, docker, database-connection, firewall

Trying to connect to a sql Server fails. Port does not seem to be reachable.

```
docker container ... 0.0.0.0:15106->3306/tcp
```

SQL is running on 3306.
In the Docker Container:

```
state       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                 Local Address:Port                                                                Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      80                                                         127.0.0.1:3306                                                                           *:*
```

On the Server:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :15106
tcp6       0      0 :::15106                :::*                    LISTEN      30494/docker-proxy
```

All authorizations are granted, but it is not possible to establish a connection.

```
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
```

```
telnet [ip] 15106
Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify MySQL host in the `PMA_HOST` environment variable. You sould also use `PMA_PORT` to specify port of the server because it might not the be default one.

```
docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=dbhost -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Source: [Official phpMyAdmin Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/)